# Potential Leak of an object in UYLPasswordManager

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I experimenting with the UYLPasswordManager from [iOS and Keychain Migration and Data Protection - Part 3](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/06/02/ios-and-keychain-migration-and-data-protection-part-3.html) and am getting a warning in analyze that there is a potential leak of an object on the [result release] line of code. Is this a real potential leak? If so how do I fix it? If not how do I silence the warning? My project uses ARC, but I have turned it off with a flag for the UYLPasswordManager object.

```
- (void)searchKeychain {

if (self.keychainValue == nil) {
NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self newSearchDictionary];

[searchDictionary setObject:(id)kSecMatchLimitOne
                     forKey:(id)kSecMatchLimit];
[searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                     forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

NSData *result = nil;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,
                                      (CFTypeRef *)&result);
[searchDictionary release];

if (result) {
   self.keychainValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [result release];
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your keychainValue property is declared as copy or retain its the new NSString you are creating. Add an autorelease message like this:

```
self.keychainValue = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```